# Django Object Serialize And Custom Date Formatting

Tags: python, django

So I am using this code to serialize Django objects to a JSON format (so I can send to RabbitMQ over Celery):

```
import django.core.serializers as serializers
import json

def serialize(obj):
    d = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', [obj]).strip('[]'))
    filtered_fields = {
        'id': d['pk'],
    }
    for key, value in d['fields'].iteritems():
        filtered_fields[underscore_to_camelcase(str(key))] = value
    return filtered_fields
```

This returns something like:

```
{
    "firstName": "Foo",
    "lastName": "Bar",
    "createdAt": "2013-12-15T20:53:59.615",
    "updatedAt": "2013-12-15T20:53:59.615",
    "dateOfBirth": "1990-05-17",
    "id": "foo@bar.com"
}
```

Is there a way to tell the Django serialiser to convert date time objects to a Zulu format? So instead of:

```
2013-12-15T20:53:59.615
```

I want:

```
2013-12-15T20:53:59Z
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use django's simplejson for serializing you could do something like:

```
simplejson.dumps(data, cls=LazyEncoder)
```

and have that LazyEncoder take care of special cases like translations and in your case datetimeformat:

```
class LazyEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return #your formatting goes here
```

Only problem is that simplejson.dumps returns string. But if you look into it, then perhaps you can use the same lazyencoder for your purposes (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2). Just an idea here - i have not had the need to dig deeper into this, so i am not sure if this is useful to you